# How to use JSFL to import lot of bitmaps from different folder to library and keep the folder structure in fla file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, jsfl

I need to import lot of bitmap files from different folders to library of fla file and keep the folder structure in fla file.

So fo example i have structure of files like that:

mainFolder -> folder1 -> png1.png 
mainFolder -> folder1 -> folder11 -> png2.png 
mainFolder -> folder2 -> png3.png 
mainFolder -> folder2 -> png4.png

I need to have the same structure in fla file in library:

folder1 -> png1.png
folder1 -> folder11 -> png2.png
folder2 -> png3.png 
folder2 -> png4.png

For now I've menage to create this code:

```
var dom = fl.getDocumentDOM(); 
var URI = fl.browseForFileURL("select", "Import File");
var success = dom.importFile(URI);
if(success)
{
    fl.trace(flash.documents[0].name);
    var indexOfFileName = URI.lastIndexOf("/");
    var folderStructure = URI.slice(URI.indexOf(flash.documents[0].name),indexOfFileName);
    dom.library.newFolder(folderStructure); 

    var fileName = URI.slice(indexOfFileName + 1,URI.length);       
    dom.library.moveToFolder(folderStructure, fileName, true);
}
```

// mainFolder in my case is the name of fla file (with .fla extention)

This code creating the folder structure as I need to but I don't know yet how to load more than one file at once just pointing the main folder for example by 
`fl.browseForFolderURL("Select a folder.")`

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to programmatically import assets into your working .fla, while mirroring the same directory structure, for the purpose of a clean GUI workflow?  If so, might I encourage the opposite?  Keep your FLA file size down to a minimum so that your exported swf is as small as possible.  Then, load your assets externally, and dynamically.  Should allow for more responsive, lightweight, application. That's my experience, at least; I'm not sure what you're aiming for.

Comment: I have old structure of fla files. I need to export all graphis from them to the desktop optimize graphics in external tool and load them back with the same structure to fla file. I've already create jsfl file for exporting the graphics but i dont know how to import optimizet png's back automatically. BTW if anyone need jsfl file that can export all graphics/bitmaps/sounds from library just tell me. Still please help me with automatic loading files.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i made it. If anyone will need something like that this is my solution:

```
fl.outputPanel.clear()
var folderURI = fl.browseForFolderURL("Select a folder.");
fileList = new Array()

function listFile(paths){
    var files=[]
    var folds=[]
    var files=FLfile.listFolder(paths,"files"); 

    for(i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    {   
        if(paths.lastIndexOf("/") != paths.length -1 )
        {
            paths+="/";         
        }
        fileList.push(paths + files[i]);
    }
    var folds = FLfile.listFolder(paths , "directories");

    for(var j=0;j<folds.length;j++)
    {           
        var subPath = paths + folds[j] + "/"        
        listFile(subPath);  

        //make sure that this stops at a reasonable point.
        if (fileList.length > 1000)
        return;
    }
}


function importFile(URI)
{
    var success = dom.importFile(URI);
    if(success)
    {       
    var indexOfFileName = URI.lastIndexOf("/");
    var documentName = flash.documents[0].name;             
    var folderStructure = URI.slice(URI.indexOf(documentName) + documentName.length + 1,indexOfFileName);
        if(folderStructure)
            dom.library.newFolder(folderStructure); 
        var fileName = URI.slice(indexOfFileName + 1,URI.length);       
        dom.library.moveToFolder(folderStructure, fileName, true);
    }
    return;
}

listFile(folderURI);

for(i=0;i<fileList.length;i++)
{
    fl.trace("fileList["+i+"]="+ fileList[i]);
    importFile(fileList[i])
}
```

name of the main folder with photos has to be the same like name of the fla
for example folder has to have name test.fla

Comment: nice job. One note, this second bit of code is missing the line setting the dom variable, so I added var dom = fl.getDocumentDOM();